# Files .class in Source Tree after clone

Tags: java, bitbucket, sourcetree

I have cloned a repo from BitBucket with Source Tree, and I open the project with Eclipse. I didn't change nothing, but in "Unstaged file" I have all the relative .class file. 
I think they are binary files; I should remove or ignore them?
Thanks.

Comment: They're the class files that were automatically compiled by Eclipse. Also, you *think* that .class files are binary files? How long have you been programming in Java?

Answer (score 0):

You should add the target folder to your .gitignore (https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Right click on the .class file, go to ignore...